# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named after publishing a package to PyPI with Poetry

Tags: python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry

I created a package with poetry with this folder instruction:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ models/
│  ├─ helpers/
│  ├─ file_a.py
│  ├─ file_b.py
├─ __init__.py
├─ tests/
│  ├─ tests.py
├─ __init__.py
├─ pyproject.tmol
```

In `file_a.py` I do `from file_b import FileB` and then I can it use like: `b = FileB()`,
and in my `tests.py`, I do `from file_a import FileA` and all works fine while doing development, but when I publish the package to PyPi and try to use in another project:

```
from file_a import FileA
a = FileA()
```

I get something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "src/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kinetic_sdk import KineticSdk
  File "/Users/me/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/kinetic-python-example-17HFj6yJ-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/file_a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from file_b import FileB
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_b'
```

FWIW: package name would be `file-a`

Comment: Many things seem wrong here. I think the directory structure needs to be changed, I recommend you to let Poetry create the directory structure with [`poetry new --src my-package`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#new). Then make sure to always use absolute import; this means the imports should always start with the name of the top-level importable package.

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for replying, so I did try `poetry new --src file-a` to follow what I have and my new directory structure is not different from what I already had. Could you please point me to what is that see as many things wrong here or how would you change it? Thank you.

Comment: Edit the question to add the content of the `pyproject.toml` file. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks! since it is open source I will just point the repo better, I might be missing some info in my original question. So my is this [pyproject.toml](https://github.com/kin-labs/kinetic-python-sdk/blob/main/pyproject.toml)
and [file_a](https://github.com/kin-labs/kinetic-python-sdk/blob/main/src/kinetic_sdk.py) and [file_b](https://github.com/kin-labs/kinetic-python-sdk/blob/main/src/kinetic_sdk_internal.py). Is this more helpful to identify the issue? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Git repo does not seem to be public.

Comment: Sorry, what about now?

Comment: Now I can see the repo. The Python files in `src` have to be moved to `src/kinetc_sdk`, that would be the first step. There is no need for `__init__.py` in the root directory.

Comment: move just the the `.py` files or everything inside `src`?

Comment: Thanks, for pointing me in the right direction. It works.

Comment: @sinoroc So all works fine, but to import it now, I have to do something like 
`from kinetic_sdk.kinetic_sdk import KineticSdk`, is there any way I can get rid of the double kinetic_sdk?

Comment: No mystery, it is straightforward: ***A.*** you can move the code of `KineticSdk` into `src/kinetic_sdk/__init__.py`; or ***B.*** you can add the line `from kinetic_sdk.kinetic_sdk import KineticSdk` in `src/kinetic_sdk/__init__.py` (but then there are 2 ways to import the class, which I do not like personally).

Comment: I had another look at your git repo: ***1.*** you should move `src/__init__.py`, to `src/kinetic_sdk/__init__.py`; ***2.*** you should move the `src/generated` directory to `src/kinetic_sdk/generated`. -- The point is that `kinetic_sdk` should be the one and only top-level import of the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just published [my first package to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/nbdbsession/) and ran into the same issue. This is how I solved it.

You can install your package like it is indicated on the [MyPI website](https://pypi.org/project/nbdbsession/) (in my case: `pip install nbdbsession`).

**Your import, however, will be based on the folder name.**

We need to change your file structure.

#### This is your original structure:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ models/
│  ├─ helpers/
│  ├─ file_a.py
│  ├─ file_b.py
├─ __init__.py
├─ tests/
│  ├─ tests.py
├─ __init__.py
├─ pyproject.tmol
```

#### This is what you need to change:

- The `+` indicates something you need to add
- The `-` indicates a removal
- The `~` indicates a change

```
my-app/
├─ src/
+ ---myapp/ # put everything into the folder "src/myapp/"
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ models/
│  ├─ helpers/
│  ├─ file_a.py
│  ├─ file_b.py
- ├─ __init__.py # you only need the __init__.py file in "src/myapp"
├─ tests/
│  ├─ tests.py
- ├─ __init__.py # same here: no need to store that file here
~ ├─ pyproject.toml # there was a typo here :)
```

Or in essence:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
|  |-myapp/
│    ├─ __init__.py
│    ├─ models/
│    ├─ helpers/
│    ├─ file_a.py
│    ├─ file_b.py
```

Once your package is published, you can run `import myapp`, where `myapp` is **the name of the folder**.

#### Another Example

Let's say you had this struct:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
   |-zen/
     ├─ __init__.py
     ├─ ...
```

You would indeed `import zen` after `pip install my-app`.

#### A few more notes:

Why do you need the `__init__.py` file? This file will let Python know that the current directory is a module / package. Therefore, you only need it in your package folders, not in the root directory or in src.

When you import within a module, you usually do [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) ([python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)).

So instead of `from file_b import FileB` you would use `from .file_b import FileB`.

And if you want to import `file_b` after installing your package with `pip install myapp`, you need to `from myapp import file_b`.

I hope that helps!